# Json Webservice not found in Spring MVC Web App

Tags: java, web-services, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc

I've got a Spring web application and this application has two aspects! one is a Json webservice and the other is a static view. When I start the web app and use the URL to go to the view, it works fine. But when I try to connect to the Json web service, the server returns a 404 error.

Here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!--  SPECIFIC CONFIGURATIONS -->
    <import resource="springConfigurations/common-config.xml"/>
    <import resource="springConfigurations/mvc-config.xml"/>

    <bean id="exceptionResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.exception.JsonExceptionResolver">
        <property name="exceptionView">
            <value>jsonView</value>
        </property>
        <property name="errorHandler">
            <list>
                <ref bean="statusError" />
                <ref bean="modelFlagError" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="exceptionHandler">
            <list>
                <ref bean="exceptionMessageExceptionHandler" />
                <ref bean="stackTraceExceptionHandler" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="exceptionMessageExceptionHandler" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.exception.ExceptionMessageExceptionHandler" />
    <bean name="stackTraceExceptionHandler" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.exception.StackTraceExceptionHandler"/>    

    <bean name="statusError" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.error.HttpStatusError" />
    <bean name="modelFlagError" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.error.ModelFlagError" />

</beans>
```

This is the common-config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

        <!--  COMMON CONFIGURATIONS -->
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <tx:annotation-driven/> 

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.jkcs.touchpos.application.controller" />

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
            <property name="location">
                <value>/WEB-INF/views.xml</value>
            </property>
            <property name="order" value="0" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp">
            <property name="order" value="1" />
        </bean>

        <!-- Annotations based Configuration -->
        <context:annotation-config />


        <!-- Components Auto-Detection (Backend) -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.jkcs.touchpos" use-default-filters="false" >
            <!-- Types annotated by Spring Managed, Controller and Transactional, or by an annotation that itself is 
            annotated by SpringManaged, Controller, Transactional -->
            <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="com.jkcs.touchpos.platform.annotations.SpringManaged"/>
            <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
            <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional"/>
        </context:component-scan>

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

</beans>
```

Views.xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <bean name="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView"/>

</beans>
```

The service class.

```
@Controller
public class TouchPosService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/service", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView sampleJsonService(){

        Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
        model.put("Value", "Test Service to provide touchPos Data");

        return new ModelAndView("jasonView", model);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here! I've defined two view resolvers with given priority! but some how it's not working! Please help me with this!

Thank you.

Update :

The console logs the following when the server starts.

```
2013-04-22 13:40:51.384:INFO::Logging to StdErrLog::DEBUG=false via org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.jkcs.touchpos.server.jetty.ServerRunner).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
2013-04-22 13:40:51.384:INFO::jetty-7.0.0.v20091005
2013-04-22 13:40:51.947:INFO:/:Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
2013-04-22 13:40:53.509:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9157
```

And the following 404 is thrown from the browser!

[image]

Comment: Which URL are you using to access it? Do you get any exceptions during startup?

Comment: Turn on debug level logging and see what is logged when you get the 404. It should provide hints as to what is wrong with the configurations. Looking at so much XML in the question is a difficult way to spot what's wrong.

Comment: I'm using http://localhost:9157/service to access the service and http://localhost:9157/layout to access the layout. The server starts fine with no exceptions.

Comment: could you post any error messages, and also, the full controller code? including the imports!   also, do you see your mappings when startin? should look like: 2013-04-22 16:01:58,282 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Mapped "{[/],[.....]

Comment: I updated my question with console out puts and the error I get!

Comment: Do you have a file `jasonView.jsp` in your `/WEB-INF/jsp/` folder?

Comment: I dnt have a jasonView.jsp there but, the views.xml is located in the WEB-INF folder.

Answer (score 1):

You're mapping the view as jsonView `<bean name="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView"/>` but later on in the return method of your controller, you're returning `ModelAndView("jasonView", model);`

Are these meant to both be the same?  I can see if you're returning the wrong name of the jsp file here that would cause the 404.

Comment: these are meant to be the same! the ModelAndView just returns the model to the front end!

Comment: Yeah but if it's trying to return jasonView.jsp and it's named jsonView.jsp that would explain your 404

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri This is probably the correct answer. Since the `XmlViewResolver` has no entry for `jasonView`, it goes to the next view resolver in the chain, which is the `InternalViewResolver`, which looks for the view in the `/WEB-INF/jsp` folder.

Comment: you are correct! :) when I return the ModelAndView, it search for a view so, since there is no view called jasonView, it'll return a 404! :)

Comment: Cool, if this answers your question would you mind accepting the answer, if it doesn't though amend your question with anything that's missing.